# jenkins slave on server with custom port

Tags: jenkins, port, slave

I've installed jenkins on suse 12.1 and changed the port in the config to 8081

```
/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

JENKINS_PORT="8081"

The webinterface works without any problem on this port, but when I want to start the client with JNLP he gives me the standardport:

```
javaws http://192.168.1.137:8080/computer/192.168.1.190/slave-agent.jnlp
```

Now I tried to run it with the right port:

```
javaws http://192.168.1.137:8081/computer/192.168.1.190/slave-agent.jnlp
```

But after a short time I get an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.137:8080/jnlpJars/remoting.jar
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.137:8080/jnlpJars/remoting.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

He tries the wrong port. How can I change the port correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you updated the URL via the configuration option under Manage Jenkins → Configure System → Jenkins URL?